# Force Appium to keep running even when app is inactive

Tags: instruments, appium

I'm currently debugging some ui tests written for an iOS app.

I've written the tests in java using the selenium web driver package, along with appium to convert these into something Apple Instruments can understand.

When I set breakpoints in my code I want to be able to spend some time looking at variables, functions etc. However when I spend over a certain amount of time (maybe about 15 seconds) debugging - appium closes the simulator.

In the log I get `info: Instruments exited unexpectedly`.

Does this mean its more of an Instruments problem or is there some setting or command I can give to force the session to stay open even when the app is inactive?

Answer (score 1):

in your test setup include the following capability

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 100000);
```

this should be all you need to make the timeout longer so you can debug